# AS3 TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. (button and gotoAndPlay)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button

I have a scene with 4 frames. On the first frame there is two buttons, `Instructions` and `Start`. `Instructions` lead me to frame 4, where the instructions are, and `Start` leads me to frame 2, where the game is. After the game finish, I am led to frame 3, where there is a button that says main menu, which should redirect me to the main menu. However, the main menu button does not work, and causes `Error #1009` as posted in the title. I apologize in advance for any foolishness, as this is my first time using AS3. Here is the code:

```
public function projectFinal()

    {
        startBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
        instructionBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, instructions);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyboardDown);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyboardUp);
        specialTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, spawnBonus);
        monsterTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, moveMonsters);
        mainBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, endGame);
        backBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goBack);
    }

    function startGame(event:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        gotoAndPlay(2);
        gameStarted = true;
        specialTimer.start();
        monsterTimer.start();
        spaceShip.score = 0;
        //createMonsterRow(monsterRow);

    }

    function instructions(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        gotoAndPlay(4);
        trace ("pressed ins");
    }

    function endGame(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        gotoAndPlay(1);
        trace("pressed main");
    }

    function goBack(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        gotoAndPlay(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have ActionScript on every frame and you don't have a stop(); at the end of each frame in the code, the application will just jump from one frame to the next.  Put a stop(); after the goBack function and on all the other frames and see if that works.

Comment: Hi there, stop(); did not solve the problem unfortunately. I moved the mainBtn and backBtn eventListeners out of the public function, and put them under their own functions pasted below. The Null error is now gone, I now have no errors, but the back button and the main menu button still refuse to work.                                                         function goBack(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
   backBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goBack);
   gotoAndPlay(1);
   trace ("pressed back");
  }

Comment: To add to this, I threw in trace statements for the buttons that are not working, when I hit the button, it does not give me output. I'm guessing this is a layer issue, the eventListeners cannot find the buttons because it's not on the first frame. Sigh.

Comment: Make sure the button and event listeners are all on the same frame and  see if spanning them across all 4 frames works.  The stop(); command prevents the app from cycling through the frames and gives control to the code to make the jump back or forward.  Each frame has to have a stop() for this to work.